# Printing Comments in Visio 2016

Tags: macros, comments, microsoft-visio-2016

I can't figure out how to print the comments I've included in my Visio diagram.  I found a macro that was supposed to work in Visio 2013. It did create an object that had the title headers, Reviewer, Date and Comment. However, there was no text.
I'm guessing that the macro is mostly right but missing something that has changed from Visio 2013 to Visio 2016.
Can anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of Michael's script with the following changes:
Columns are Number and Comment instead of Initials Date and Comment.
Run a counter that starts at 1. 
For each shape with a comment, append the counter # to the shape's text, and prefix the comment with the counter #. This makes it work like endnotes with a way to easily figure out which comment goes with which shape. Note that like it continues to only work on the active visio tab.

```
Sub CommentsToPrint()
    Dim oPage As Visio.Page
    Dim oShape As Visio.Shape
    Dim oComments As Visio.Comment
    Dim sText As String
    Dim noteNum As Integer

    Set oPage = Visio.ActivePage
    sText = "Number" & vbTab & "Comment"

    'Loop through comments creating a string containing them all, and adding note numbers
    noteNum = 1
    For Each oComment In oPage.Comments
        oComment.AssociatedObject.Text = oComment.AssociatedObject.Text & " [" & noteNum & "]"
        sText = sText & vbCrLf & noteNum
        'sText = sText & vbCrLf & oComment.AuthorInitials
        'sText = sText & vbTab & oComment.EditDate
        sText = sText & vbTab & vbTab & oComment.Text
        noteNum = noteNum + 1
    Next oComment

    'Create a new shape with all the comments attached as visible text
    'Save the current value of autosize, create a rectangle using autosize=0     then restore autosize to its orignal value
    'The rectangle is created as the same size as the current page but immediately to the left of it
    Dim iAutoSize As Integer
    iAutoSize = oPage.AutoSize
    oPage.AutoSize = 0
    Set oShape = oPage.DrawRectangle(-oPage.PageSheet.Cells("PageWidth").ResultIU, 0, 0, oPage.PageSheet.Cells("PageHeight").ResultIU)
    oPage.AutoSize = iAutoSize
    'Set the text alignment for the rectangle to Top/Left
    oShape.Cells("Para.HorzAlign").Formula = "0"
    oShape.Cells("VerticalAlign").Formula = "0"
    'Give it a name and add the comments to it
    oShape.Name = "Review Comments"
    oShape.Text = sText
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since this was asked but I ran into the problem today so threw together a quick and dirty script that creates a rectangle to the left of the current page (similar to other solutions I've seen) then attaches all comments from the active page to the new object.  I think the issue is because the model for comments in Visio 2016 is totally different to what it was previously.

If this helps anyone feel free to use it

```
'This is in no way comprehensive and is not intended to be production quality
'It does what it does
'Michael Cameron July 2018

Public Sub ShowComments()
Dim oPage As Visio.Page
Dim oShape As Visio.Shape
Dim oComments As Visio.Comment
Dim sText As String

Set oPage = Visio.ActivePage
sText = "Initials" & vbTab & "Date" & vbTab & "Comment"

'Loop through comments creating a string containing them all
For Each oComment In oPage.Comments
    sText = sText & vbCrLf & oComment.AuthorInitials
    sText = sText & vbTab & oComment.EditDate
    sText = sText & vbTab & oComment.Text
Next oComment

'Create a new shape with all the comments attached as visible text
'Save the current value of autosize, create a rectangle using autosize=0     then restore autosize to its orignal value
'The rectangle is created as the same size as the current page but immediately to the left of it
Dim iAutoSize As Integer
iAutoSize = oPage.AutoSize
oPage.AutoSize = 0
Set oShape = oPage.DrawRectangle(-oPage.PageSheet.Cells("PageWidth").ResultIU, 0, 0, oPage.PageSheet.Cells("PageHeight").ResultIU)
oPage.AutoSize = iAutoSize
'Set the text alignment for the rectangle to Top/Left
oShape.Cells("Para.HorzAlign").Formula = "0"
oShape.Cells("VerticalAlign").Formula = "0"
'Give it a name and add the comments to it
oShape.Name = "Review Comments"
oShape.Text = sText
End Sub
```